# Careers backend doesn't enforce messaging restrictions

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), if you apply for a job and go to `messages`→`sent`, you can see your application and:

> You must wait until the employer responds to your application

But if you remove the `disabled="disabled"` attribute from the message text area and submit button, plus set `ng-disabled="canSendMessage(thread)"`, you can actually send messages even though it is forbidden. The backend does not appear to check this in any way.

To reproduce:

1. Apply for a job
2. Go to messages->sent
3. Remove everything marked with green colour on picture 2
4. Send a message

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can you tell is was really sent? Do you see another message in your "Sent" folder?

Comment: I tested it. Sent a message to one of my applications, that was not replied. Looks pretty stupid now, but it worked. Yeah, i can see it in my sent folder

Comment: Hmm... so it's rather a major bug, not minor.

Comment: yeah, just did not really want to write it in public. Can i send a screenshot somehow?

Comment: Sure, you have "Image" toolbar icon in the editor click it to open the image upload dialog. Here on MSE it should be enabled for everyone.

Comment: oh, great, thought I need rating to add pictures:) added some screenshots.

Comment: On all other sites you need 10 rep, but this one is different. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Status confirmed, status fixed. How's that for turn around time?

Comment: fix should be up in production in the next 10 minutes (or less) :)

Comment: @rla4 Sorry, feel free to answer next time so I don't steal your credit!

Comment: nah, np! I added that comment just in case someone tried to reproduce it before the fix reached prod ;D

Comment: great, that you are taking care of it that fast. Nice job!

Comment: @evl the Careers team is beyond excellent, I'm here for long time and never saw a bug they responsible to survive more than couple of days. ;)